# TagHelper is not rendered

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have interesting problem with TagHelpers in .NET Core 2.0. Original helpers work seems right. But customs not. I wrote code inspired original Image helper (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ImageTagHelper.cs), but still not working.

**This is my helper:**

```
namespace MyApp.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("Blob", Attributes = FilenameAttributeName + "," + AltAttributeName, TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class BlobTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public BlobTagHelper() { }

        private const string FilenameAttributeName = "filename";
        private const string AltAttributeName = "alt";

        [HtmlAttributeName(FilenameAttributeName)]
        public string Filename { get; set; }


        [HtmlAttributeName(AltAttributeName)]
        public string Alt { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "img";
            //...
        }
    }    
}
```

**In _ViewImports.cshtml I have simply this:**

```
@using MyApp

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, MyApp //MyApp.TagHelpers
```

**Razor view look this:**

```
<blob filename="@mainImage.Filename" alt="@mainImage.Title" />
```

**In csproj I have deps:**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
```

this package should has TagHelpers references: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.all

Finally result on page looks this:

```
<blob filename="babylon.jpeg" alt="babylon.jpg"></blob>
```

I've got no error or exception, just is not rendered.

**EDIT**

Here is separated project with not working `<email>` helper.
https://github.com/petrck/dotnet-taghelper-sample

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tell what’s going on but just as a hint: You do not need (or should) list all the element’s attributes in the `HtmlTargetElement` attribute. The attribute is used to match tag helper usages and for each attribute usage, all of the constraints need to apply. So for example, in case you were omitting some (optional) attributes for this question, that might be the problem here. Just do `[HtmlTargetElement("blob")]` and don’t require any attributes but just map them using the `HtmlAttributeName` attribute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you have is on this line:

```
@addTagHelper *, MyApp //MyApp.TagHelpers
```

Although it looks like a comment, `//MyApp.TagHelpers` is invalid on this line and is tripping up the `TagHelper` discovery logic.

Just remove that part and it'll work. i.e.:

```
@addTagHelper *, MyApp
```

Comment: The reason why this works is because the `@addTagHelper` syntax expects an assembly name as its second part (not a namespace).